# overlapping of 3 intervals: what is the fastest way

Tags: javascript, python, logic, intervals, overlapping

Give 3 intervals (a,b) , (c,d) , (e,f), what is the fastest way to detect (i.e. have a yes/no answer) if exists a value t that is at the same time `a<=t<b AND c<=t<d AND e<=t<f ?`
Is it also possible to compute the range of t that satisfies this condition, `min(t),max(t)` ?

Moreover, is it possible to do the same without any hypotesis about the order? (i.e. it could be also `b<a` or `a<b`)

I've found a well known solution for two segments but for three is not trivial.

Any js or python example code is welcome.

EDIT: corrected condition requirements

Comment: These are basic maths... Just order the boundaries first.

Comment: I know they are basic maths, I've asked what is the best algorithm to get the result (the fastest way)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python solution for any number of intervals regardless of order of the numbers in the interval. It'll either return `True, min t value, max t value` or `False, t value, t value`.

```
def in_interval(intervals):
    if len(intervals) == 0:
        return False, None, None
    min_t = min(intervals[0])
    max_t = max(intervals[0])
    for interval in intervals[1:]:
        min_t = max(min_t, min(interval))
        max_t = min(max_t, max(interval))
    if min_t > max_t:
        return False, None, None
    else:
        return True, min_t, max_t
```

Test run:

```
>>> intervals = [(6,1),(2,20),(8,7)]
>>> in_interval(intervals)
(False, 1, 1)
>>> intervals = [(6,1),(2,20),(4,9)]
>>> in_interval(intervals)
(True, 4, 6)
```

Comment: Wait. Something wrog with it ... in the declaration of in_interval t and interval list are required, but you are calling it passing just the t. However I need to know the min_t and max_t without guessing an initial t. if I pass a t that is not in all the intervals I got False,t,t that is useless to me.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I get for not fully copy/pasting from my terminal. Fixed the function calls to pass in both t and the intervals you're looking at. My bad.

Comment: ok. but I have no t to pass to ... I have just the list of intervals and i want to know the overlap range. I've not to test if a given t is in the range.

Answer (score 0):

```
def order(ab):
    (a, b) = ab
    if a is None or b is None: return None
    if a>b: 
        return (b,a)
    else:
        return (a,b)

def order2(ab, cd):
    if ab is None or cd is None: return None
    (a, b) = order(ab)
    (c, d) = order(cd)
    if a <= c:
        return (ab, cd)
    else:
        return (cd, ab)

def intersect(ab, cd):
    if ab is None or cd is None: return None
    ((a, b), (c,d)) = order2(ab, cd)
    if b <= c:
        return None
    if d < b:
        return (c, d)
    else:
        return (c, b)

def intersect_of_three(ab, cd, ef):
    return intesect(intersec(ab, cd), ef)
```

Answer (score 0):

my first solution is to sort the range in order to have all intervals in the form `[x,y]` with `x<y`.
Then I compute

```
overlap_x=max(a,c,e)
overlap_y=min(b,d,f)
```

The full overlap exists if and only if

```
overlap_x<overlap_y
```

where overlap_x and overlap_y are the boundaries of the overlapping range.

Do you know if there is a faster solution that requires less operations ?

Comment: if two of them overlap, you do not need to test the 3rd one.

Comment: But is what I need ... read the condition: ... if exists a value t that is at the same time a<=t<b AND c<=t<d AND e<=t<f. Thus, it two intervals overlap it is no neccessary true that the third covers the same coverlapping range.